# Error en la recepción de datos php con AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

**Intento pasar un dato a través del método POST con ajax, pero en el archivo php al que lo mando no consigo que recoja los datos.
Adjunto código.**

Aqui es donde con ajax intento mandar los datos, a mi php que recibe el array de POST vacío.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function contratar(valor){
            alert(valor);
            $.ajax({
                data: { id: valor },
                url:'contratar.php',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(){
                    alert("Proveedor correctamente añadido");
                    window.location = 'contratar.php';

                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                }

            });
        }
    </script>
```

Aquí por medio de php voy haciendo echo y más tarde hago un onclick que llamará a la función donde esta ajax.

```
<div class="catalogo">
        <table class="table" > 
            <?php
                $contador=0;
                $resultado = mostrarProveedores();
                foreach($resultado as $valor){
                    foreach($valor as $valor2){

                        if($contador==3){
                            echo '<tr>';
                            $contador=1;
                        }
                        else{
                            $contador++;
                        }

                        echo '<th style="text-align:center;">';
                        echo '<img src="uploads/'.$valor2.'" alt="Proveedor" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" height="130px" width="130px">';
                        echo '<br>';
                        echo '<input type="button" value="Contratar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="contratar(\'.$valor2.\')">';
                        echo '</th>';
                    }
                }


            ?>
        </table> 

    </div>
```

El problema esta en que $_POST['email'] es nulo.

```
function contratar(valor) {
            let str = "email=jorge";
            alert(valor);
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("POST", "contratar.php", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhttp.send(str);
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                let a = this.responseText;
                console.log(a);
                }
            };

        }
```

Comment: Revisa la configuración de ajax, los datos no se pasan así, más bien es data: { id: valor }. Además, considera poner el código como código y no como imagen, así facilitas las cosas.

Comment: Te lo pongo con el ajax de jquery: data: { id: valor, email: "jorge" }, aunque imagino que el correo es en realidad el usuario que está trabajando con la web, entonces es mejor guardar dicha variable en una session en el momento del login para que un usuario malicioso no pueda falsearla.

Answer (score 0):

Debes enviar los parámetros dentro de un objeto y no como un string en esta parte de tu código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function contratar(valor){
        alert(valor);
        $.ajax({
            data: 'id='+valor,
            url:'contratar.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(){
                alert("Proveedor correctamente añadido");
                window.location = 'contratar.php';

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

¿Cómo quedaría el código ajax enviándolo correctamente?

Reemplaza la línea donde mandas `data:'id='+valor` por `data : {id : valor}` donde `{id : valor}` es el objeto que recibe y envía n números de valores con la estructura "clave" y "valor".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function contratar(valor){
        alert(valor);
        $.ajax({
            data: { id: valor },
            url:'contratar.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(){
                alert("Proveedor correctamente añadido");
                window.location = 'contratar.php';

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

En tu código PHP donde estás haciéndole el POST, tienes que hacer referencia a la misma clave que enviaste desde ajax como `$_POST["id"]`

El error que te está mencionando es que no encuentra ninguna llave en `$_POST` ya que como te dije anteriormente, nunca se la estás mandando.

Además, la línea que muestra el input, está mal, mejor usa esta otra:

```
echo "<input type='button' value='Contratar' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='contratar(\"$valor2\")'>";
```

Te dejo esta referencia sobre [cómo mandar parámetros con ajax](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/fundamentos-jquery/capitulo-7/metodos-ajax-de-jquery) y qué es un [objeto en javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos).

Comment: Corregí con tus aportaciones, pero sigo sin recibir en el php. Me he dado cuenta, de que si hago un alert de mi variable 'valor' la que paso por parámetro a la función no es legible. Podría ser debido a que los caracteres de la función onclick no están como deberían? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Veo que ocupas un echo `'<input type="button" value="Contratar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="contratar(\'.$valor2.\')">';` No es necesario que concatenes la variable como lo estás haciendo. Cambia eso por esto: `'<input type="button" value="Contratar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="contratar('.$valor2.')">';` y dime si ya recibes algo en tu alert

Comment: La concatene porque al hacerlo como me dices, me sale el siguiente error:Uncaught ReferenceError: naturalPizza is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (proveedores.php:58)                                           Mi script esta en la misma página por lo que creo que debería reconocer la función.

Comment: Una duda con eso, `$valor2` qué tipo de dato es? Te lo pregunto porque si es numérico está bien como te lo mandé, pero si no es así, yo te recomiendo hacerlo de otra manera, para que siempre tomes el valor que sea y lo mandes por ajax, vi que ya actualiazste tu pregunta,

Comment: Cambia la línea '<input type="button" value="Contratar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="contratar(\'.$valor2.\')">'; por esta otra "<input type='button' value='Contratar' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='contratar('".$valor2."')'>";

Comment: A la pregunta de Fernando, se trata de un string. Como me recomendarías hacerlo ?

Comment: Sobre la recomendación de track3r, la he probado y me surge el siguiente error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input, algo se me escapa pero no caigo en el problema.

Comment: En ningun momento veo que recojas la variable id que envias por ajax en el backend, con php para obtener la informacion de los parametros por post debes de usar= $_POST['nombreVariable'], en tu caso = $_POST['id']

Comment: Entiendo que el problema está en que la función contratar no recoje el valor "valor2" y muy probablemente es porque no concatenas correctamente en PHP el valor que le quieres asignar (¿has mirado el html generado a ver si es correcto?). Normalmente, yo no genero el html desde PHP, me gusta tener el html separado de la capa de php, en tu caso, creo un div oculto a modo de plantilla, luego con jquery y una llamada ajax, llamo a un php que me devuelve un json con los valores de la tabla y clono el contenido del div template desde jquery recorriendo el json con los valores que toca en cada caso.

Comment: Pero con tu código, he probado en un php online y la línea es así: echo "<input type='button' value='Contratar' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='contratar(\"$valor2\")'>"; Puedes verla en funcionamiento en http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e9d70ccc59b3f691616bac3dc37d09621e60cfef Edito la respuesta para reflejar el cambio

Comment: Por cierto, revisando un poco, no entiendo porque quieres entrecomillar el $valor2 en la función contratar si se trata de un entero. Así que no hace falta poner comillas, quedaría así: contratar($valor2)

Comment: Es correcto tu solución me sirve, pero ahora el problema es que no me sirve el envío de datos desde ajax. He probado también con ajax puro y no me ha servido en el php la recogida mediante el indice. Edito mi pregunta con la duda.

Comment: Revisa la petición ajax desde el inspector de elementos a ver si realmente se hace el post o el problema está en la recogida del valor en la parte php.

Comment: Lo he comprobado escribiendo un echo "hola" en la parte de php, y me lo devuelve por tanto creo que el problema esta en la recogida del valor con php.

Comment: Tienes que mirar en el apartado red, el filtro XHR la pestaña de Parámetros, a ver si realmente estás pasando las variables desde ajax. Esto desde un firefox, en otro navegador no recuerdo... pero será similar.